# PostgreSQL indexes for hstore boolean attributes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, hstore

I have an hstore column called **extras** and I have defined there many attributes some of them are boolean and I would like to index some of them for example `extras->'delivered'` in this case which would be the best way to index some of these attributes.

If you answer could you tell me if your technique applies for decimal or other types.

Thanx.

Answer (score 6):

### Indexing individual keys in a `hstore` field

The current `hstore` version doesn't have typed values. All values are `text`. So you can't directly define a "boolean" index on an hstore value. You can, however, cast the value to `boolean` and index the cast expression.

```
CREATE INDEX sometable_extras_delivered_bool 
ON sometable ( ((extras->'delivered')::boolean) );
```

Only queries that use the expression `(extras->'delivered')::boolean)` will benefit from the index. If the index expression uses a cast, the query expressions must too.

This b-tree index on a hstore field will be less efficient to create and maintain than a b-tree index of a boolean col directly in the table. It'll be much the same to query.

### Indexing all keys in a `hstore` field

If you want a general purpose index that indexes *all* hstore keys, you can only index them as `text`. There's no support for value typing in hstore in PostgreSQL 9.3. 
See [indexes on hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#AEN147387).

This is useful when you don't know in advance which keys you need to index.

*(Users on later, pre-release at time of writing versions of PostgreSQL with the json-compatible hstore version 2 will find that their `hstore` supports typed values).*

### Reconsider your data model

Frankly, if you're creating indexes on fields in a `hstore` that you treat as boolean, then consider re-thinking your data model. You are quite likely better off having this boolean as a normal field of the table that contains the `hstore`.

You can store typed values in `json`, but you don't get the GIN / GiST index support that's available for `hstore`. This will improve in 9.4 or 9.5, with hstore 2 adding support for typed, nested, indexable hstores and a new json representation being built on top of that.

### Partial indexes

For booleans you may also want to consider [partial index expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) where the boolean is a predicate on another index, instead of the actual indexed column. E.g:

```
CREATE INDEX sometable_ids_delivered ON sometable(id) WHERE (delivered);
```

or, for the hstore field:

```
CREATE INDEX sometable_ids_delivered ON sometable(id) WHERE ((extras->'delivered')::boolean);
```

Exactly what's best depends on your queries.

Comment: I have moved from using tables to HSTORE, my model is using a base model called Account from which other models inherit but require additional attributes. Why I moved from tables to HSTORE, because when I want to present all accounts it much easier to present all of them using hstore no need to make joins and loads much faster. About **partial indexes** these index works like a function that checks if the attribute is beign set when you create or update a record?.

I'm using **ruby on rails** and eager loading would not work.

Comment: @BorisBarroso You know PostgreSQL has [inheritance features](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) right? Best of both worlds for your use case I think. I have no idea what you are asking re partial indexes, I cannot understand. See the documentation.

Comment: @CraigRinger: So so, because OP would then lose the ability to play with foreign keys due to the data living in multiple tables. What OP would actually need here in practice is 0:1 relations for child models.

Comment: @Denis True. I really, really wish someone was keen to fix the issues with Pg's table inheritance re FKs, it'd be a great deal more useful. It's also really hard to do, I've looked into it and my brain nearly melted.